# only single row comes from the json api

Tags: flutter, dart

I am beginner in flutter ,I used an `API` of soccer to get some information of player transferts ,so I have created a model class that contains only the information that I need to ,but when I executed, I had this error:

```
E/flutter ( 5073): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
E/flutter ( 5073): #0      new Transferts.fromJson (package:tl_fantasy/models/transfert_json.dart:12:26)
E/flutter ( 5073): #1      _PlayerDetailsState.getTeams.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:tl_fantasy/players/player_details.dart:45:45)
```

So I changed my model class
if i put this in the model class it works when i put it for example `json['transfers'][0]['date']`,  but the problem is it gives me only the first result , what i need is all results, how to replace[0] by a kind of index or something? how to take all elements?

Here the json that i am trying to access:

```
{
  
  "response": [
    {
      "player": {
        "id": 35845,
        "name": "Hernán Darío Burbano"
      },
      "update": "2020-02-06T00:08:15+00:00",
      "transfers": [
        {
          "date": "2019-07-15",
          "type": "Free",
          "teams": {
            "in": {
              "id": 2283,
              "name": "Atlas",
              "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/2283.png"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "date": "2019-01-01",
          "type": "N/A",
          "teams": {
            "in": {
              "id": 1937,
              "name": "Atletico Atlas",
              "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/1937.png"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here my model class tranfert_json:

```
     class Response {
  Player player;
  String update;
  List<Transfers> transfers;

  Response({this.player, this.update, this.transfers});

  Response.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    player = json['player'] != null ? new Player.fromJson(json['player']) : null;
    update = json['update'];
    if (json['transfers'] != null) {
      transfers = new List<Transfers>();
      json['transfers'].forEach((v) { transfers.add(new Transfers.fromJson(v)); });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.player != null) {
      data['player'] = this.player.toJson();
    }
    data['update'] = this.update;
    if (this.transfers != null) {
      data['transfers'] = this.transfers.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Player {
  int id;
  String name;

  Player({this.id, this.name});

  Player.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    return data;
  }
}

class Transfers {
  String date;
  String type;
  Teams teams;

  Transfers({this.date, this.type, this.teams});

  Transfers.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    date = json['date'];
    type = json['type'];
    teams = json['teams'] != null ? new Teams.fromJson(json['teams']) : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['date'] = this.date;
    data['type'] = this.type;
    if (this.teams != null) {
      data['teams'] = this.teams.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Teams {
  In teamIn;

  Teams({this.teamIn});

  Teams.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    teamIn = json['in'] != null ? new In.fromJson(json['in']) : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.teamIn != null) {
      data['in'] = this.teamIn.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class In {
  int id;
  String name;
  String logo;

  In({this.id, this.name, this.logo});

  In.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    logo = json['logo'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['logo'] = this.logo;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Here my player_details class:

```
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:tl_fantasy/models/transfert_json.dart';

class PlayerDetails extends StatefulWidget {

  int id;
  String name;
  String lastname;
  String image;
  String club;
  String position;
  String nationality;
  String age;
  int matches;
  String goals;
  String assists;
  String saves;


  PlayerDetails({this.id,this.name, this.lastname,this.image, this.club, this.position,
      this.nationality, this.age, this.matches, this.goals, this.assists, this.saves});

  @override
  _PlayerDetailsState createState() => _PlayerDetailsState();
}

class _PlayerDetailsState extends State<PlayerDetails> {

  List<Response> teams = [];

  Future<void>  getTeams(int id) async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(
        'https://v3.football.api-sports.io/transfers?player=$id',
        headers: {'x-rapidapi-key': 'c52370f8295e1525b7f7ba38655e243f',
          'x-rapidapi-host':'v3.football.api-sports.io'});
    String body = response.body;
    var data = jsonDecode(body);
    List<dynamic> clubList = data['response'];

    setState(() {
      teams = clubList
          .map((dynamic item) => Response.fromJson(item))
          .toList();
    });

  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getTeams(widget.id);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    if(widget.matches == null ){
      widget.matches == 0;
    }
    if(widget.goals == null ){
      widget.goals == "0";
    }
    if(widget.assists == null ){
      widget.assists == "0";
    }
    if(widget.saves == null ){
      widget.saves == "0";
    }

    List<Stats> stats = [
      Stats("Matches", widget.matches.toString() ),
      Stats("Goals", widget.goals ),
      Stats("Assists", widget.assists ),
      Stats("Saves", widget.saves ),
    ];



    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Player Details"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue[300],
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                end: Alignment.centerRight,
                colors: [Colors.purple, Colors.blue])
        ),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                  end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  colors: [Colors.purple, Colors.black38])),
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0,0,8.0,0),
                width: double.infinity,
                child:    Card(
                  elevation: 4.0,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    child:
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          height: 60,
                          width: 60,
                          child:
                          Image.network(this.widget.image,
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(width:10.0),
                        Spacer(),
                        Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                          children: <Widget> [
                            Text(widget.name, style: TextStyle( fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 18.0,
                            )),
                            Text(widget.lastname, style: TextStyle( fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 18.0,
                            )),
                            const SizedBox(height: 5.0, ),
                            Text(widget.club, style: TextStyle( fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 18.0,
                            )),
                            const SizedBox(height: 5.0, ),
                            Text("Role : "+widget.position, style: TextStyle( fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.grey[600],
                            )),
                            const SizedBox(height: 5.0, ),
                            Text("Age : "+widget.age, style: TextStyle( fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.grey[600],
                            )),
                            const SizedBox(height: 5.0, ),
                            Text("Nationality : "+widget.nationality, style: TextStyle( fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.grey[600],
                            )),

                          ],
                        ),

                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 15, 0, 0),
                child:  Text(
                  "Season Stats",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900, color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),

              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                  child: GridView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: stats.length,
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: 2,
                        crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                        mainAxisSpacing: 4.0
                    ),
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                      return Card(
                        child: Center(
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 5, 0, 0),
                                  child:  Text(stats[index].result,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                  child: Text(stats[index].title,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0)),),

                              ]
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  )
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 10),
                child:  Text(
                  "Teams",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900, color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),

              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 5, 0),
                child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics : NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index){
                    return Card(
                      elevation: 4.0,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      ),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        child:
                        Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            CircleAvatar(
                              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(teams[index].transfers[index].teams.teamIn.logo),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(width:10.0),
                            Spacer(),
                            Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                              children: <Widget> [
                                Text(teams[index].transfers[index].teams.teamIn.name, style: TextStyle( fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 18.0,
                                )),
                                const SizedBox(height: 5.0, ),
                                Text("joined : "+teams[index].transfers[index].date, style: TextStyle( fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.grey[600],
                                )),
                              ],
                            ),

                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  itemCount: teams.length,
                ),
              ),

              SizedBox(
                height: 70,
              ),
            ],
          ),

        )
      ),
    );
  }
}


class Stats{

  String title;
  String result;

  Stats(this.title,this.result);

}

class Team {

  String name;
  String image;
  String date;

  Team(this.name,this.image,this.date);

}
```

i am trying to find a  way to get all results , not just the first index of my api json

Comment: use [quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io/) to convert your json to dart class

Comment: i tried and i did it already but i failed to access the fields in my player_details

Comment: it works when i put in my model file for example json['transfers'][0]['date'],  but the problem is it gives me only the first result , what i need is all results

Comment: You have to convert it to list of object

Comment: i did this but , i have to put an index for the transferts in the listview and it still give me one result

Comment: this is how i access transferts teams[index].transfers[index].teams.teamIn.name but this gives me only the first result

Comment: can you post the code

Comment: i did this now , check the update

Comment: try to replace `List<dynamic> clubList = data['response'];` with `List<dynamic> clubList = data;`

Comment: and you may need to use nested listview , for the second itemCount use transfers list length

Comment: can you show me how to do a listview.bulder inside a listview.builder to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example of nested ListviewBuilder , don't forget to add `shrinkWrap` inside the listview

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: teams.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          List<Transfers> transfers = teams[index].transfers;
        return ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: transfers.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Text(transfers[index].teams.teamIn.name);
         },
        ) ;
       },
      ),
    );
  }
```